# higher temperature or more lighting - whats more important?

Tags: growth, bell-peppers

I'm trying to choose between 2 places to grow young bell peppers which will be transplanted in a few weeks.

The first one is outside with plenty of natural light. Temperatures during the day are between 16-20°C.

The second one is below a roof window which gets a lot of direct sunlight and plenty of ambient light too. But still less then the outside. Temperature is above 22-23°C at all time.

To sum it up, roof window plants get 20% less light than the outside ones, but experience 5°C higher temperatures.

Where should I grow plants?

Comment: I think with these small temperature differences, the amount of light is more an important factor. But your situation sounds like an ideal setup of an experiment, to find out what's better. Why don't you put half of the plants outside, and the other half under the window and see at the end what is best?

Comment: will do that  and post the results:)

Comment: I agree with b.nota's suggestion, but the temperature thats more important is the overnight temps outdoors, because that will be much lower than indoors. That only matters if it gets cold overnight though...

Comment: It gets as low as 11°C

Comment: That's a bit low, they're better if the temperature stays above 15degC overnight, but at least its not low enough for a frost.

Comment: I would cover my plants when the temps get that low...pepper are easily ruined by too cold temperatures.  Newspaper slightly moistened is the best little blanket for plants for a night of too cold temps.  Newspaper is an amazing insulator.  Just a few sheets, moistened, lightly draped over your plants will protect very well against a night of too cold.  Light is more important for plants that you want to provide fruit or even flowers.

Comment: Make no mistake you have to acclimate your peppers before transplanting them out of doors.  This takes a good 2 or 3 weeks. After acclimating the peppers to their out of door garden BED, and then transplanting, I would still cover my peppers when it will be a cold night...less than 45 degrees Fahrenheit.  I really gotta learn to do Celsius and metrics.  Grins.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Majority of the plants are happily growing in the soiI. Unfortunately, I had to cancel the experiment with the little ones due to aphid infestation. Now all the plants are outside where ladybirds can take care of them.